# Larger than normal output values?

Tags: c

The program runs but i'm getting some silly values output and i'm not sure why. Could anyone offer some insight?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

// Declare values and open weather.txt
FILE *gpep;
int k;
float  wind[11], temp[11],  num[11], minT=800, maxT=12, minW=800, maxW=9, 

sum_wind=0, sum_temp=0, avgW, avgT;
    gpep = fopen("gpep.txt", "r");


if (gpep != NULL){
gpep

        for (k = 0; k < 13; k++)
        {
        fscanf(gpep, "%f %f %f" , &num[k], &wind[k], &temp[k]);


        sum_wind += wind[k];
        sum_temp += temp[k];
        avgW= sum_wind/13;
        avgT= sum_temp/13;

        printf("Average Temp: %f \n Average wind: %f \n", avgT, avgW);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Can't Open\n" );
    }

fclose(gpep);

getchar();
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better if we see `weather.txt`, and you can check what have you read just putting `printf()` immediately after `fscanf()`.

Comment: Please format your code properly. It is barely readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computation of max and min are wrong, look at this:

```
if (wind[k] > maxW) {
    wind[k]=maxW;
}
```

it changes your data! Should be like:

```
if (wind[k] > maxW) {
    maxW=wind[k]; // stores a greater value in maxW
}
```

You also have problems with integer division, consider using doubles:

```
double avgW; // declare it as a real
```

and next:

```
avgW = sum/13.0; // floating division
```

But, we don't understand why you divide by 13??? Should not be a constant but the current number of read elements:

```
avgW = ((double)sum)/(k+1); // convert one to double to ensure correct division
```

---EDIT---

You also have problems with initialization, in fact you don't initialize avg, sum, etc. You must! Initialize them as sum=0, max=less possible value, etc:

```
int sum=0;
int maxW = INT_MIN;
int minW = INT_MAX;
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, the max temp, sum temp and avg temp seem to be correct now. Though for some reason my min values are both 0 and the max win sum wins and avg wind are absurdly high numbers.

Comment: I guess i misunderstood initializing. I always thought it would turn my int/float into a constant. Everything works now but the wind calculations. They seem to be reading from the first column opposed to the last one.

Comment: "have problems with integer division" is unclear as variables are `float`.  Perhaps an early version of OP's post?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is because of the integer division (i.e. `sum_wind/13` and `sum_temp/13`). You should declare them as `float` or `double` variables in order to get correct division results. Integer division produces the result truncated to zero.

Comment: This is not quite so. Integer division produces the quotient from the nearest smaller dividend integrally divisible by the divisor and _ignores_ the division remainder. _Modulo_ operation produces the division remainder, AFAIK.